# Python3 calling csv.DictReader - object is not callable

Tags: python, csv

I am new to Python, and writing a simple code to categorise my daily expenses. The program reads csv files with transactions, performs some math, and then prints out the results. Thanks in advance for your support.

**Problem**: when calling csv.DictReader for the second time in code gives an error.

**Error**:
line 12, in  csv.reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ';')
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/csv.py", line 86, in **init**
self.reader = reader(f, dialect, *args, **kwds)
TypeError: 'DictReader' object is not callable

```
import csv

ledgerDebit = []
ledgerCredit = []

with open('jan2022_full.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csv.reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ';')
    for row in csv.reader:
        ledgerDebit.append(row)

with open('jan2022credit_full.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csv.reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ';')
    for row in csv.reader:
        ledgerCredit.append(row)
```

Comment: why did you do: `csv.reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ';')`? That overwrights the `reader` attribute on the `csv` module with a `DictReader` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
csv.reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ';')
```

use

```
import csv

ledgerDebit = []
ledgerCredit = []

with open('jan2022_full.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ';')
    for row in reader:
        ledgerDebit.append(row)

with open('jan2022credit_full.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ';')
    for row in reader:
        ledgerCredit.append(row)
```

`reader` is just a variable of the class reader, if you use `csv.reader = ...` you are essientially trying to overwrite a class definition within the `csv` module

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Comment: oh, gosh, what a silly error I made. I just followed a reco from VS code. Indeed it works now. Thanks a million

Comment: feel free to accept the answer if it works for you :-)